# When more load FIWARE Orion service getting error 'Timeout was reached' forwarding 'Update' to providing application

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to provision a device and send actuation commands back using 1 component Orion.

I have successfully provisioned the device using to update orion query:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://orion:1024/v2/op/update' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: agriculture' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /agriculture' \
  -d '{ 
  "actionType":"update",
  "entities":[{"motor":{"type":"command","value":{"requestTime":"2023-11-17T06:50:00.060",
"payload":{"motor_status":"on","requestTimestamp":"2023-11-17T18:49:59.091",
"motor_status":"on"},"transactionId":"xxxx-87a5-4xxx2-xxx-xxxxxxx"}},"id":"urn:ngsi-ld:test:test1","type":"test"}]}
```

I am facing, and after trying, I have obtained this error:

```json
{"error":"NotFound","description":"The requested entity has not been found. Check type and id"}
```

while Orion reported

> fiware-orion Starting transaction to http://orion:1024/v2/op/update

```
fiware-orion   | ERROR@10:16:34  postUpdateContext.cpp[190]:Runtime Error (error 'Timeout was reached' forwarding 'Update' to providing application)
fiware-orion   | INFO@10:16:34  logMsg.h[1874]: Transaction ended
```

Thank you in advance I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your provider is incorrect. You have used the batch upsert operation to create an entity in Orion called `urn:ngsi-ld:test:test1`. However your registration is circular, it is forwarding `"attrs": ["on", "off"]` to  `http://orion:1024/v2/op/update` - this would mean that the registant service would receive a batch request on  `http://orion:1024/v2/op/update/v2/op/update` which does not exist.

Even if you altered the provider to `http://orion:1024`, that is still wrong, as a context broker shouldn't registering directly back onto itself - you should be using another microservice such as an [IoT Agent](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-agent.html) to translate the NGSI actuation request down to a low level protocol understood by a device.

Comment: Thank you @Jasaon Fox , I required your help, this Orion issue, I am getting this error **Runtime Error (error 'Timeout was reached' forwarding 'Update' to providing application)** in the Orion log info, I am getting timeout error all 420 devices after 10 minutes time internal for every start.

Comment: Thank you @fgalan, I tried to increase the environment value **ORION_HTTP_TIMEOUT from 5 sec (default) to 20 secs**, After increasing the ORION_HTTP_TIMEOUT value, the number of timeout errors in orion came down from about 15000 to **2000** . Is it the right approach or do you have any suggestions ?