# Orion Runtime Error (error 'Timeout was reached' forwarding 'Update' to providing application)

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We have an IoT platform environment on AWS EKS that uses a fiware stack comprising iotagent, Orion (version 3.4.0), and Draco.

Our objective is to conduct scalability testing for 420 devices. For every 50 seconds, a command request is sent from a device simulator to the spring boot application API(running on EKS), this in turn calls ORION and updates the payload in Mongodb of ORION.

the payload will send a Batch update Orion call (POST http://orion:1026/v2/op/update), using fiware-service and fiware-servicepath with payload.

Please find the payload information below.

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://orion:1026/v2/op/update' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: building' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /building' \
  -d '{"actionType":"update",
  "entities":[{"heater":{"type":"command","value":{"requestTime":"2023-11-17T18:50:00.060",
  "payload":{"heater-heater_7_status":"on","requestTimestamp":"2023-11-17T18:49:59.091",
  "heater-heater_8_status":"on"},
  "transactionId":"fbxxx679-87a5-4xxx-83fb-049xxxxxc7df"}},
  "id":"urn:ngsi-ld:Equipment:heater001",
  "type":"Equipment"}]}
```

We are facing this error in the spring boot application REST API call response from Orion:

```json
{"error":"NotFound","description":"The requested entity has not been found. Check type and id"}
```

Upon checking Orion log , we see below message response:

```
fiware-orion   | ERROR@10:16:34  postUpdateContext.cpp[190]: Runtime Error (error 'Timeout was reached' forwarding 'Update' to providing application)
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If so, could you please share the solution that worked for you?

I am grateful for your assistance!

Comment: Do you have some registration covering the entity you are updating (urn:ngsi-ld:Equipment:heater001)?

Comment: Duplicated question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77515003/when-more-load-fiware-orion-service-getting-error-timeout-was-reached-forwardi ?

Comment: Do you have some registration covering the entity you are updating (urn:ngsi-ld:Equipment:heater001)? **YES**,  It is sample data.

Comment: Also @fgalan, I tried to increase the environment value **ORION_HTTP_TIMEOUT from 5 sec (default) to 20 secs**, After increasing the ORION_HTTP_TIMEOUT value, the number of timeout errors in Orion came down from about 15000 to **2000** . Is it the right approach or do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If after increasing `ORION_HTTP_TIMEOUT` your error timeout rate has decreased, that seems to be a good idea. In addition, I'd recommend you:

- To review your network setup. Maybe some issue external to Orion itself (e.g. network latency) is the root cause of the problem.
- To have a look to the [performance tuning document](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/admin/perf_tuning.md)

With regards to the specific `Runtime Error` trace you get, note that it disappear in Orion 3.6.0 given it is redundant (more detail [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/4052/files#r796540190)). I'd recommend you to upgrade to newest Orion version (at the moment of writing this, it is Orion 3.10.1 but it can be even newer in the moment you read this :) and test again.